# Select table in cursor after creating the table

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

just want to ask for some help, i created a script that will check first if the table is existing already. If the table is not existing, then i need to create a table then i will select it in cursor. I only need to create the table once, then if the table is existing i should only insert the data. this should be address in one sql script only.

The Problem is when i try to execute my script, it shows that the "table or view does not exist" it seems that cursor is trying to validate it already when i run my script. is there a way to address this issue?

```
DECLARE 
tbl_exist_s1 PLS_INTEGER;
tbl_exist_s2 PLS_INTEGER;
total_were_updated_sc2 NUMBER(10,0);
total_need_to_update_sc2 NUMBER(10,0);
total_were_updated_sc1 NUMBER(10,0);
total_need_to_update_sc1 NUMBER(10,0);
run_date Date := SYSDATE;


BEGIN

  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(NULL);
  --Checking if the table is already existing, create table if not existing.
  select count(*) into tbl_exist_s2
  from all_tables
  where owner = 'cent' AND table_name = 'serv_req';

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cleanup run: ' || SYSDATE);

  if (tbl_exist_s2 = 0) THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Start Creating table cent.serv_req');

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE cent.serv_req (      
    association_type NUMBER(10,0), 
    association_id NUMBER(10,0), 
    association_id_serv NUMBER(10,0),
    request_id NUMBER(10, 0)
    record_audit_datet DATE,

    CONSTRAINT pk_sc1 PRIMARY KEY(association_type, association_id, association_id_serv))';
END IF;

-- this is to insert the new data to the table.
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO cent.serv_req
      VALUES(12, 13, 14, 1172, SYSDATE)';
commit;

 DECLARE
 v_err_comp CHAR(2000);
 c SYS_REFCURSOR;

 CURSOR sample_cursor IS
 select *
 from cent.serv_req
 where record_audit_date = run_date;

 sample_cursor_rec sample_cursor%ROWTYPE;
 BEGIN
   -- This will count the no of the records that are getting updated
   total_need_to_update_sc2 := 0;
   total_were_updated_sc2 := 0;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('===Starting process to activate the component element record associated to the active member instance record===');

-- this loop is to update the component element
OPEN sample_cursor ;
  LOOP
    FETCH sample_cursor INTO sample_cursor_rec;
      EXIT WHEN sample_cursor % NOTFOUND;

       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('===sample===');
        --Logic should be here
    END;

  END LOOP;
CLOSE sample_cursor;
END;

END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has to compile the block before it can run it.  Part of compiling the block is verifying that all the referenced objects exist and that's the step that fails for you since the table doesn't exist.  There are two basic ways around that.

- You can break your script up into two separate PL/SQL blocks.  The first creates the table if it doesn't exist.  Then the second implements whatever logic you want to implement.
- If you need this to be a single PL/SQL block, you would have to use dynamic SQL everywhere you reference the table.  You could open a cursor using a dynamic SQL statement and/or use the [`dbms_sql` package](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm#BABEDAHF) to run the subsequent queries.  That adds a fair amount of complexity to your code, however, so it is generally not ideal.

Comment: I tried to separate them into 2 PL/SQL block, but when i run them, the cursor is still looking for the table.

Answer (score 1):

See if the following helps. This is an excerpt from your code:

```
select count(*) into tbl_exist_s2
from all_tables
where owner = 'cent' AND table_name = 'serv_req';     --> this

<snip>

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE cent.serv_req (       --> this

<snip>

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO cent.serv_req          --> this
```

By default, Oracle stores object names (which includes owner namess, table name, column names, ...) in **UPPERCASE**.

Therefore, `SELECT` you ran returned 0 because it really didn't find a table whose name is `serv_req` (lowercase) owned by user `cent` (lowercase again).

Then, using dynamic SQL, you're trying to create a table and insert into it, but this time referencing it "normally" (i.e. `cent.serv_req`) which is correctly interpreted by Oracle; unless table name is enclosed into double quotes (so MiXEd CAsE matters), Oracle *knows* what to do.

Shortly: try to switch to `UPPERCASE` in the first select, i.e.

```
select count(*) into tbl_exist_s2
from all_tables
where owner = 'CENT' AND table_name = 'SERV_REQ';     --> this; use UPPERCASE
```

---

Furthermore, you can't reference a table that doesn't exist yet - that's what your CURSOR is trying to do. If you want to do it, you'll have to switch to dynamic SQL again, which is slowly turning into a nightmare.

Here's your code, modified, which actually compiles and *does something*:

The first part:

```
SQL> declare
  2    tbl_exist_s1             pls_integer;
  3    tbl_exist_s2             pls_integer;
  4    --total_were_updated_sc2   NUMBER(10,0);     --> moved to ...
  5    --total_need_to_update_sc2 NUMBER(10,0);     --> ... another PL/SQL ...
  6    total_were_updated_sc1   number(10,0);
  7    total_need_to_update_sc1 number(10,0);
  8    --run_date                 Date := SYSDATE;  --> ... block
  9  begin
 10    dbms_output.enable(null);
 11    --Checking if the table is already existing, create table if not existing.
 12    select count(*) into tbl_exist_s2
 13      from all_tables
 14      where owner = 'SCOTT' and table_name = 'SERV_REQ';
 15
 16      dbms_output.put_line('Cleanup run: ' || sysdate);
 17
 18    if (tbl_exist_s2 = 0) then
 19       dbms_output.put_line('Start Creating table cent.serv_req');
 20
 21       execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE scott.serv_req (
 22         association_type    NUMBER(10,0),
 23         association_id      NUMBER(10,0),
 24         association_id_serv NUMBER(10,0),
 25         request_id          NUMBER(10,0),          --> missing comma here
 26         record_audit_date   DATE,
 27         CONSTRAINT pk_sc1 PRIMARY KEY(association_type,
 28                                       association_id,
 29                                       association_id_serv))';
 30    end if;
 31
 32    -- this is to insert the new data to the table.
 33    execute immediate 'INSERT INTO scott.serv_req
 34        VALUES(12, 13, 14, 1172, SYSDATE)';
 35    commit;
 36  end;
 37  /
Cleanup run: 09/28/2019
Start Creating table cent.serv_req

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

The second part:

```
SQL> -- This should be a new PL/SQL procedure as you can't reference table that
SQL> -- doesn't exist (yet)
SQL> declare
  2    total_were_updated_sc2   number(10,0);
  3    total_need_to_update_sc2 number(10,0);
  4    run_date                 date := sysdate;
  5
  6    v_err_comp               char(2000);
  7    c                        sys_refcursor;
  8
  9    cursor sample_cursor is
 10      select *
 11      from scott.serv_req
 12      where record_audit_date = run_date;
 13
 14    sample_cursor_rec sample_cursor%rowtype;
 15  begin
 16    -- This will count the no of the records that are getting updated
 17    total_need_to_update_sc2 := 0;
 18    total_were_updated_sc2 := 0;
 19
 20    dbms_output.put_line('===Starting process to activate the component element record associated to the active member instance record===');
 21
 22    -- this loop is to update the component element
 23    open sample_cursor ;
 24    loop
 25      fetch sample_cursor into sample_cursor_rec;
 26      exit when sample_cursor % notfound;
 27
 28      dbms_output.put_line('===sample===');
 29      --Logic should be here
 30      --END;  --> this doesn't have its BEGIN; remove it
 31    end loop;
 32    close sample_cursor;
 33  end;
 34  /
===Starting process to activate the component element record associated to the active member instance record===

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

In my opinion, you should think it over. Don't create tables dynamically, that's rarely a good idea. Create it once using pure SQL and use it later as many times as you want. Dynamic SQL is *nice to have*, but it doesn't scale, is difficult to debug, tends to grow into a monster which will make your life (as a developer) miserable.

Comment: I've seen that there is a another way to define like a cursor. I read about instead declaring my select in the cursor, put it on the "Open" like this: "Open sample_cursor FOR '' select * from cent.serv_req where record_audit_date = run_date", but it seems when i used this, i need to declare a avariable for every column just to access it inside the loop? any thoughts about this one?

Comment: See if refcursor helps.